# Responsive images with high performance

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm making a new webiste and I want to configure it to load different image in mobile version.

I saw some solutions that can fit my needs.
My question is what is the best solution for high performance.
What is the solution that will prevent the explorer to load unnecessary contents.

One method is using html5's  element:

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="img_smallflower.jpg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
 <source srcset="img_flowers.jpg">
  <img src="img_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers">
</picture>
```

Another method is using css display property:

```
.img-responsive.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .img-responsive {
    display: none;
  }
  .img-responsive.mobile {
    display: block;
 }
}
<body>
    <img src="img_flowers.jpg" class="img-responsive careerpage">
    <img src="img_smallflower.jpg" class="img-responsive careerpage mobile">  </body>
```

I don't know any other methods.
I would like to know what is the best option for high performance
thank you

Comment: I recommend using the `<picture>` element for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set a few CSS attributes to the img-responsive class, for example:

```
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I want to load completely different image in mobile version.